# Stopping external function call after timeout in Swift

Tags: swift, macos, task, external

I am integrating some Swift code with some external C library, whose source code is unavailable. I can easily call the C function I need, but sometimes the function gets stuck for reasons I cannot predict.
What I would like to do is 1) call the function, 2) get the result if it arrives within, say, 10 seconds, 3) if the timeout passes, "kill" the call to the C function and continue normal program execution.

In other answers on SO (like [Timeout function after 10 seconds Swift/iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40167786/timeout-function-after-10-seconds-swift-ios) and [dispatch_async timeout method call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26873239/dispatch-async-timeout-method-call)) the stopper owned the code to be stopped, but here I don't, so I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: do you have access to the kill function in the external library?

Comment: @Russell I'm not sure what you mean. I just have the .a library file with the corresponding .h, which lists the header of the function I call. I don't think the author of the library has made any kill function available for my purpose. So the "killing" needs to happen at some other level, if at all possible

Comment: well, that's a shame :-(

You can certainly stop waiting for the response within your code, and reinitiate the call, but doesn't look like you can do much if you don't have access to externalFunction.KillMeNow()